# Debug Rails application in RubyMine + Apache + Passenger environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, debugging, passenger, rubymine

My application behaves in a strange way when is running on production server in CentOS 6.5 + Apache + Phusion Passenger (For those who will ask for particularities: TCP sockets are periodically disconnected from live data server. Rails app is acting like TCP client). In WEBrick and Puma it works flawlessly.

Ok, I decided to reproduce the production environment on VMWare virtual machine and yes, the disconnects are just like on production server when running on Apache + Passenger.

Then I decided to install X-Window + RubyMine to perform live debug in Passenger. But I was unable to reproduce the strange behaviour when running Passenger only, without Apache.

How to reproduce Apache + Passenger environment while debugging in RubyMine?

How to debug the app except using `puts` or some other logging?

I suspect that the bug is in some way related to multi-process execution of the app.

Comment: Can u please post the solution if u found it..i am sticking with the same problem.thanks in advance